# Unknown Battery Connector

Tags: batteries, connector

[image]
Hi, this is a standard 260mAh 3.7V battery. I've seen this on several listings on eBay, Aliexpress however nobody says what this connector is.

In particular I'm looking for the receptacle part of this that I can place on a PCB.

Comment: Give some measurments of the pins and the housing

Comment: @laptop2d I literally can't find any information about this. I haven't bought it yet and I'm designing a board around it.

Comment: the picture is not clear enough for determining what the connector actually looks like .... please provide a link to one  of the listings

Comment: is it  like this one? ... https://www.amazon.com/Accessories-Batteries-Yoton-Quadcopter-Accessory/dp/B07RTBLSCL

Comment: @jsotola Yes, it is.

Comment: You should ask the eBay and Aliexpress sellers.  EE.SE isn't their volunteer application support.

Answer (score 1):

I can find that exact battery with a few different connectors...
Most likely it's JST or Molex.

I found it with both the JST PH and XH connectors.

PH is a 2mm pin spacing

XH is a 2.5mm pin spacing

It also looks like a Molex 51005.

This is an in line only connector.  It's only mate is the 51006, for inline connections....

Can I recommend that you purchase the battery from a domestic supplier?  There's a datasheet for this battery, looks like it might be a good fit for you.
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/battery-products/batteries-rechargeable-secondary/91?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv33=725&sf=1&FV=ffe0005b%2Cfffc05f8&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 0):

That is a SYMA battery connector.

Image search for `260mAh 3.7V battery` lead to this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07RTBLSCL/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RTBLSCL)

Which lead to an image search for `quadcopter battery connector` and got this result https://outger.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SYMA-RC-Quadcopter-Battery-Connector-Conversion-04.jpg

Which lead to a search for `SYMA` and got this [https://www.amazon.com/10pairs-2-0mm-Battery-Female-Connector/dp/B073ZH79Y1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073ZH79Y1)

Could not find a PCB mount version though.

Looks like this may be the manufacturer store. http://www.symatoystore.com/Syma-Spare-Parts/Syma-X5C-Spare-Parts

Comment: I guess I can always cut it off and re-crimp new JST connectors.